# How to do code coverage and create reports in Visual Studio 2012 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2012, code-coverage

I'm trying to do code coverage and create reports in VS2012 Pro, which doesn't include the CodeCoverage.exe and the rest of the tools (As in Ultimate and Premium). I've looked through a lot of examples, and they usually seem to take the generated data file and convert it into xml. When I try to use (compile) that code, it complains about missing assemblies, which in turn seem related to the fact that I'm using the Pro version (as opposed to the Premium and Ultimate).

I have a script that generates the coverage data to a .vsp file, but when using the VSPerfReport.exe (which seemed like a good fit), it fails with:

> Error VSP1712: Invalid File: myexename.vsp
>   Error: VSP1804: Did not successfully open the file.

I want to create an html page in the end, and can probably do that by getting an xml first.
I also tried to open the coverage file in VS but it couldn't read the file.

So, I wonder if it's at all possible to do this with the tools provided in the Pro version?

---

Here is the script:

```
@echo off

set EXE=<path to exe>\<exename>
set OUTPATH=.\coverage
set OUT=%OUTPATH%\<exename>
set ARGS=<some args>

rem I've seen this extension in several examples, but it generates:
rem Error VSP1712: No readers configured for the .coverage file extension. Check the ReaderFactoryConfig file.
rem set VSP=%EXE%.coverage

rem This extension generates the error message:
rem Error VSP1712: Invalid File: <path to exe>\<exename>.vsp
rem Error: VSP1804: Did not successfully open the file.
set VSP=%EXE%.vsp

mkdir %OUTPATH%
vsinstr.exe %EXE% -coverage -outputpath:%OUTPATH%
vsperfcmd.exe -start:coverage -output:%VSP%

echo Running exe!
%OUT% %ARGS%

vsperfcmd.exe -shutdown

VSPerfReport.exe %VSP% /Xml /Summary:all

rm %OUT%
```

**Edit**

I use C++ programs. And free is good, so I'd like to see what my options are.

Comment: If you are looking for something free, try [OpenCover](http://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenCover) and [ReportGenerator](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ReportGenerator).

Comment: Great tips. I updated my question by specifying that I use C++ (in general, i.e. not .NET) and that rules out OpenCover. Also, ReportGenerator converts XML files, and these are the ones I cannot produce.